# Followup with Wrong answer

Tags: bixby

> I'm using followup in my result-view. When user answer with "yes or
>   no" thats works well.
>
> But what if the user answer with something else like "I don't know" it
>   will start the default-action .
>
> I want to handle that case to re-display the result-view with the same
>   input values (properties).

Comment: Thanks for surfacing this behavior. I was able to reproduce it and will chase it up with the correct folks. I will update this question when I know more!

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to experience the behavior that you desire. "Yes" takes me to the `on-confirm` step, "No" takes me to the `on-deny` step, and "I don't know" keeps me on the same view and asks the same question again.

Addressing your issue may require the team to investigate your code. In order to do so, please experience the behavior again, and submit a support ticket with the "Contact Support" option in the Bixby Developer Studio's Help menu.

Comment: you reproduce the issue before so how did you fix it.

Comment: I didn't change my code but cannot reproduce the issue anymore so I cannot debug further. For this reason, I would recommend that you experience the behavior again and submit a support ticket via Bixby Developer Studio so I can investigate further with some diagnostics data that your support ticket will contain.

Comment: i did. Here is the ticket #3937 please check it when you can

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking through it and will provide you more information via the ticket as I know more.